# ember-data exception while record is "deleted.inFlight"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble debugging this error I'm getting while deleting a record. I have a `CartItem` model that's used as part of a shopping cart.

When I delete the record and persist the change:

```
cartItem.deleteRecord()
cartItem.save()
```

This error is raised in the console:

> Attempted to handle event becameError on MyApp.CartItem:ember1606:null while in state rootState.deleted.inFlight. Called with undefined

I'm using Ember 1.0 and ember-data 0.13. I've been reading the ember-data source, and I would just like some tips on how to debug this.

Comment: Could you try with the latest ember-data ? I think this issue is now resolved.

Comment: I can't try with the latest ember-data right now, because this is connected to a large app that relies on a lot of old ember data functionality. I did try using ember-data 0.14 and saw the same behavior.

Comment: Ok. So first question, it seems weird the server respond something like an error response on delete. I don't know what do you respond to DELETE, but I think it should be a 200 with an empty payload.

Comment: That's what I figured too - that the server was giving an error on delete. But in fact the cart item is deleted successfully - the server is giving back a 200 with an empty payload.

Comment: Does the same error happen if you try to commit with the store or a transaction instead of calling save ? Also, are you sure no other action is happening on the record before the server respond ?

Comment: The error does happen if I do `cartItem.get('store').commit()` instead of `save()`. I'm looking into if anything else is happening with the record before the server responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that in old versions of Ember Data that you'd want to use `cartItem.get('store').deletedRecord(cartItem)` instead of `cartItem.deletedRecord()` and `cartItem.get('store').commit()` instead of `cartItem.save()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm getting the same error when replacing my code with `cartItem.get('store').deleteRecord(cartItem)` and `cartItem.get('store').commit()`

Comment: Well, then I don't know what you to tell you.  As sly7_7 mentioned in the comments to your question, I think upgrading to the latest Ember and Ember Data releases is probably your best bet.  Trying to maintain an app that relies on "dead" code that isn't being updated is always guaranteed to cause frustration.  If you can post a JSBin showing the issue I'll try to take a look at it.